# need help developing sql command (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, command

```
select ID, Charge_CodeID from table1
where table1.ChargeCodeID in   ('6128', '6132', '6131', '5918', '6129', '6130', '6126')
```

This is what I need help with - if i run this query and I get the following results:

```
ID           Charge_CodeID
01           6128
01           6132
01           6126
02           6131
03           5918
```

I need a command that would treat 01 6132 and 01 6126 as the same.  So ideally, I would like to see this:

```
ID           Charge_CodeID
01           6128
01           6132
02           6131
03           5918
```

It doesnt matter whether SQL selects 6132 or 6126 because essentially I want them to be seen as the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would 6132 and 6126 be treated "the same" but not 6128 which is another code with an `id` of "01"?

Comment: I have to do a count of distinct ID & Charge_CodeID, but some charge_codeID's are the same although different in number.  I cannot alter the schema or create a new table.  I only have the 'select' function as a tool to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that 6126 replace for 6132 try follows:

```
select distinct id, decode(charge_codeid, 6126, 6132, charge_codeid) from table1
```

or you can delete from you in expression value 6126:

```
select ID, Charge_CodeID from table1
where table1.ChargeCodeID in   ('6128', '6132', '6131', '5918', '6129', '6130')
```

Comment: Thanks HAYMbl4 for the tip on using the 'decode' function - hopefully it works.